# Firebase atomic write

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to ensure that 2 values are always written to the real time db together.

I have the following layout:

-> register_username

-- --> uid_lookup

-- -- --> "some_username": "some_uid"

-- --> username_lookup

-- -- --> "some_uid":"some_username"

These are the rules (Sorry for the formatting):

```
// uid -> username && username -> uid
"register_username": {

  ".write":                 "auth !== null",
  ".validate":          "newData.hasChildren(['uid_lookup', 'username_lookup'])",

    // username -> uid
  "uid_lookup": {

    "$username": {
      ".validate":  "newData.val() === auth.uid && !data.exists()"
    }

  },

  // uid -> username
  "username_lookup": {

    ".write":       "!data.exists()",

    "$uid": {
      ".validate":  "auth.uid === $uid && newData.val().matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{4,20}$/) && newData.parent().parent().child('uid_lookup/' + newData.val()).exists()"
    }

  },

  // don't allow any other children
  "$other":             {".validate": false}

}
```

When I write

```
{
  "uid_lookup": {
    "username": "123"
  },
  "username_lookup": {
    "123":"username"
  }
}
```

to `/register_username/` it works fine.

But why am I able to write to just `/register_username/uid_lookup/` without getting an error?

Comment: I just wrote an answer, but realize now that you may be asking about your validation rules only. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Database security rules validate the state of the database before and after the write operation. They do not validate the delta.

So you shouldn't try to capture illegal writes. Instead you should write your rules to only allow legal data structures.

For data under `/register_username/uid_lookup`, all you specify is that the user may only write their own uid. You probably want to add a clause that ensures they can only write a uid that also has a mapped user name:

```
"$username": {
  ".validate":  "newData.val() === auth.uid && !data.exists() &&
          newData.parent().parent().child('username_lookup').child(auth.uid).exists()"
}
```

Comment: In the end I had to use this: `".validate":  "!data.exists() && newData.val() === auth.uid && newData.parent().parent().child('username_lookup/' + auth.uid).exists()"`

Thank you!

Comment: Right, I wasn't really sure of the check you wanted there. i updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Permission cascades down in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade): once you've granted permission to a user on a certain level in the tree, you cannot take away that permission at a lower level.

Your rules start with defining the write rules for `/register_username` as:

```
".write": "auth !== null",
```

That means that any authenticated user can write all data under `/register_username` (including that node itself).